Flutter Web on Phone - TextField issue for select, copy, paste, cut, etc. - bad selection mechanism and no popups
In a Flutter Web TextField on a cell phone (chrome on iOS and Android), long-press invoked select/copy/paste/cut is not working at all consistently with non flutter text fields, is inconsistent across iOS and Android, and is essentially unusable for me.  I have a custom app, which does use bolded font (is that related to my issue?). The selector teardrops popup in weird places. And the popup menu may have no labels or not be there.
Can I expect a Flutter Web TextField (on a phone) to behave much like a traditional native text field in terms of long-press select etc? Would special packages or textfield attributes be required ? (I've tried most of the obvious options such as SelectableText and enableInteractiveSelection.) Are custom event handlers and coded popup menu needed?
Where best to learn about these aspects and make it work for/across all devices?
I am using a current version of Flutter. This has been an ongoing issue for years it seems to me. example issue I have interacted with the flutter team on github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/124483
Thank you!
My tests are using Flutter for Web and running on Chrome browser on iOS and Android - common vanilla environments.  Expected to see the usual behaviors on a cell phone - long press to get selection teardrops/markers and get a popup with options to copy/paste/cut/select...
instead the selection areas are strange
bad behaviors are different on android and iOS

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I totally know your feeling as I am in the same boat.
